# Python Selenium: keep on clicking RUN button untill 'working' message appear

Tags: python, selenium

I want to keep on clicking RUN button every after 1sec until 'working' message appears. Please advise if below code is correct:

```
#Hit Run
RUN = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@type='button']")[1]
time.sleep (5)
while True:
    try:
        RUN.click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"_NS__workingMsg")))
    except TimeoutException:
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be something like this:

```
#Hit Run
RUN = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@type='button']")[1]
time.sleep (5)
while True:
    try:
        RUN.click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"_NS__workingMsg")))
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add a if condition, that if button text matches with expected text then break out from infinite loop :

```
RUN = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@type='button']")[1]
time.sleep (5)
while True:
    try:
        RUN.click()
        working_web_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"_NS__workingMsg")))
        if working_web_element.text == "whatever button text it has on UI, should be written here":
            break
    except TimeoutException:
        break
```